# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moto'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, pip, moto

#### Problem

I cannot install the module `moto` in my `Python 3.10.13` environment, even though, it says it's installed. I followed the instructions according to `[Github][1]`, which is to install `moto[ec2,s3,all]`, but to no avail.

##### Error

```
(venv) user cloudwatch-IPaddress-lambda % python --version
pip --version

Python 3.10.13
pip 23.2.1 from /Users/ari/Documents/cloudwatch-IPaddress-lambda/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
(venv) user cloudwatch-IPaddress-lambda % pip list | grep moto

moto               4.2.12

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
(venv) user cloudwatch-IPaddress-lambda % pytest tests/test_add_ip_to_dynamodb.py
================= test session starts ==================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.13, pytest-7.4.2, pluggy-1.3.0
rootdir: /Users/ari/Documents/cloudwatch-IPaddress-lambda
plugins: django-4.5.2, anyio-3.6.2
collected 0 items / 1 error                            

======================== ERRORS ========================
__ ERROR collecting tests/test_add_ip_to_dynamodb.py ___
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/user/Documents/cloudwatch-IPaddress-lambda/tests/test_add_ip_to_dynamodb.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_add_ip_to_dynamodb.py:5: in <module>
    from moto import mock_dynamodb2
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moto'
```

Anyone else have the same issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error logged in inaccurate.
There's a module `moto`, as per my console.
However, there's no `mock_dynamodb2`. Admittedly, I used `ChatGPT` to generate this test, and it used a deprecated handler. It should be `mock_dynamodb`

[image]